# can't update my macbook to any version later than 10.7.5

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, software-update

My Macbook is 1.8 GHZ Intel core 2 DUO with 2 GB DDR2 SDRAM, version 10.7.5.  I'm not sure what year I got it but it's old.

I'm not able to perform an update to the most current version and I don't know why.

The reason I want to upgrade is that apps will not let me do an install on this OS version.  I tried installing a different OS, like Linux or Windows, but it did not go well.

It runs really well so I'm wondering if it has reached its end.

Comment: You can't upgrade your MacBook most likely because it's too old.

Answer (score 2):

There are several resources for determining if your system will take 10.8 or newer. I did a search for "minimum system requirements for 10.8" and found plenty of sources stating that your 1.8GHz Core 2 Duo powered MacBook missed the mark. So did my MacPro1,1. 
This does not mean your system has reached its end. It'll still run fine with 10.6 or 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

If you open  > About This Mac, you should find your serial number.

With that, visit the Every Mac Serial lookup page (http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/).

Once you get your result, click on the link to get the full specs. Near the bottom, there is info about the OS including the original OS installed on the machine and the last/latest version it supports.

That will give you a definitive answer.